# Grab just the number in a string variable?

Tags: string, cmd

I have multiple strings that are in the following format:

> "At Revision ###."

Where ### can be one, two, three, or four digits long.

How do I parse that string in `cmd` to only grab the number?

Answer (score 2):

try this (cmd shell script):

```
set "string=At Revision ###."
for /f "tokens=3delims=. " %%i in ("%string%") do set "number=%%i"
echo(%number%
```